# $_disableLoadDefaultDecorators and ZendX_JQuery

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

I use my class to alter decoration of my form.
In other words, instead of calling

```
Application_Form_Login extends Zend_Form
```

I use:

```
Application_Form_Login extends My_Form
```

In my "My_Form" class I define the following:

```
protected $_disableLoadDefaultDecorators = true;
protected $_elementDecorators = array(
   'ViewHelper',
   array(
      'Errors', 
      array(
         'data-icon'=>"alert", 
         'class'=>"ui-body ui-body-e errors"
      )
   ),
   'Label',
   array(
      array(
         'row' => "HtmlTag"
      ), array(
         'tag'=>"div", 
         'data-role'=>"fieldcontain"
      )
   )
);
```

This works perfect on my regular forms.
But once I use jQuery forms:

```
$this->addElement(new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_AutoComplete(
   "ac1",
   array('label' => "Your Address:"))
));
```

It has no effect on them, and they still render with their default decorators.
Any ideas how to globally set decorators for jQuery Form Elements as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. Any default decorators defined this way will also work on any ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element

#### IF

1. The element is created inside of `addElement` function. In other words, instead of creating an element this way:

   ```
   $this->addElement(new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_AutoComplete(
       "address",
       array(
           'label' => "Your Address:"
       )
   ));
   ```

   You should create it this way:

   ```
   $this->addElement('AutoComplete', 'address', array(
       'label' => "Your Address:"
   ));
   ```

   Because when `addElement` creates the element itself, it will pass the default decorators to the creating function. Otherwise the elements will be created outside of the form context.
2. There's no `AutoComplete` element in `Zend_Form`. So, the class you use to build your forms, that includes all your global settings and decorations (in my case: `"My_Form"`) should extend `ZendX_JQuery_Form`, and not `Zend_Form`
3. `ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_UiWidget` requires `UiWidgetElement` decorator. So we replace the `ViewHelper` decorator with ZendX_JQuery's: `UiWidgetElement`.